# How do I get all the dates or keywords of particular patterns before specific word using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have below string from which I need all the year range (e.g. 2018-19) coming before keyword **overall production**.

`Details                Unit/ Base 2017-18   2018-19        June (P)         April-June (P)\r\n                                                              (P)     2018-19   2019-20  2018-19   2019-20\r\n overall production 2014-15  2015-16 monthly production`

I tried with:

```
re.findall(r"(\d{4}-\d{2})", string)
```

which is returing me:
`['2017-18', '2018-19', '2018-19', '2019-20', '2018-19', '2019-20', '2014-15', '2015-16']`. Here I don't want last two year `'2014-15', '2015-16'` because it is coming after keyword **overall production**

I also tried with:

```
re.findall(r"(\d{4}-\d{2}).+overall production", string)
```

But I am getting only first year range
`['2017-18']`

Can someone please help me to write a proper regular expression so that I get all the year ranges (irrespective of counts) coming before specific keyword I pass.

Comment: The "+" in your second example is only quantifying the "." Add more parentheses if you want the whole pattern to repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.+overall production` in your second attempt consumes all the text up to and including `overall production`, and that is why only the first range is returned (there is no second `overall production` substring after this match).

You may use a lookahead based solution:

```
re.findall(r'\b\d{4}-\d{2}\b(?=.*overall production)', text, re.DOTALL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZBjcn/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d{4}-\d{2}` - four digits, `-`, two digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=.*overall production)` - a positive lookahead that requires (and does not *consume*, i.e. it does not make the regex index move with the match and does not add the text matched to the overall match value) any 0+ chars, as many as possible, followed with `overall production` substring immediately to the right of the current position.

Comment: Stribizew how can I do positive lookbehind in this same scenario? I also want to get all year ranges separately, coming after keyword "overall production".

Comment: @Shadkhan You won't be able to use `re`. You may install PyPi regex module, `pip3 install pip` and then `import regex` and then `re.findall(r'\b(?<=overall production.*?)\d{4}-\d{2}\b', text, regex.DOTALL)`. BUT you may use `re` if you first sub the string at the first occurrence of `overall production` (e.g. using `s.split('overall production', 1)[1]` or using `find`, etc.) and then just run `re.findall(r'\b\d{4}-\d{2}\b', text)`

Comment: Thank you again @Wiktor Stribiżew.

Comment: @Shadkhan Oops, I meant `pip3 install regex` / `pip install regex` :) You're welcome.